# In tikzpicture, which options has scope? Where I can find them?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'm relatively new in `tikzpicture`.

I just discovered `scope` to move and rescale objects. I wonder: which are all possible options that scope supports? I searched then in the `tikz` manual (I googled "tikz man") but I was not able to find them. Where I should look?

In a more specific example, suppose I wanto to transform a square in a parallelogram, how can I do that with scope?

Comment: see http://ctan.ijs.si/tex-archive/graphics/pgf/base/doc/pgfmanual.pdf, page126, etc

Comment: @Zarko, this is where I searched at the very beginning. At page 126 and following there is no list of what options I can use with scope. Moreover, in that manual, with CTRL+F "scope" I searched for options of scope but I did not find any.

Comment: in `scope` you ca use all options on the same way as for `tikzpicture`.

Comment: See also coordinate transformations starting on page 1045.

Comment: There are nothing specific for `scope`, a `scope` is just a way of locally setting options that apply to everything within it. For example if you do `\begin{scope}[draw=blue,ultra thick] ... \end{scope}`, the default line will be a thick blue line, instead of the usual black. So if you do `\begin{scope}[xslant=0.5] \draw (0,0) rectangle (1,1); \end{scope}` you get a parallelogram, but if that rectangle is all you have in the `scope`, you might as well just do `\draw [xslant=0.5] (0,0) rectangle (1,1);`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone} 
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0) rectangle ++(1,1);
\begin{scope}[x=0.75cm, y=2cm]
\draw[red] (2,0) rectangle ++(1,1);
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]